# qucs-core: configure error needs admsxml

Tags: configure

I'm trying to compile qucs-0.0.19 but when I put ./configure, a little after it gives me the following error:

```
checking Checking if admsXml is working...  no 
configure: error: need admsXml, but not found. consider --with-mkadms=<alternative admsXml>
configure: error: ./configure failed for qucs-core
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem and i found the solution.
Run these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Qucs/ADMS
cd ADMS
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And then try `./configure` in qucs project.

Comment: After `make install` I had to run `ldconfig` too

Answer (score 4):

I tried the `git clone https://github.com/Qucs/ADMS` solution with no success.
However, I found another solution that fixed it for me - just type

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Then, try `./configure` in qucs project.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do both clone, make, install as well as the export the LD_LIBRARY path on debian 9.x

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to specify location of the admsXml when configuring qucs.

`./configure --with-mkadms=/var/local/adms-2.3.6/admsXml/admsXml`

Answer (score -1):

I run Ubuntu 16.04 and had to do the git clone and export LD_LIBRARY_PATH to run the configure correctly. Thanks.

Comment: configure what?